# food delivery dapp: handling driver sort algorithm over smart contract?

Tags: dapps, eth-2.0

So I have a few apps- driver, customer and restaurant. I want to do randomized driver assignment (automatic) when customer places the order. Is this practical for a smart contract?

Answer (score 2):

It could be practical if you launch it on an L2 (I would suggest Matic, since it has most of the users). You could use Chainlink's VRF for randomizing the driver assignment (driver data would be contained on-chain). The contract execution TX could be initiated by the customer when they place their order on the DApp.

More about Chainlink VRF: https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf

Comment: can i write solidity?

Comment: Solidity is the main programming language on Ethereum. So, yes.

Comment: but solidity works for matic too?

Comment: Yes, definitely. It would be the same as developing for mainnet.